# How to set pages as translations of another page with php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

I am currently creating a network of landing pages with PHP and publish them on WordPress. These pages have parent-children relationships and I add meta data before I use `wp_insert_post()` in order to publish them. My code works fine but the pages are being created in English which is the WP primary language. However, the site hosts 2 more languages and uses the WPML plugin for the translations. Is there any way to create the translated pages and set them as translations of the original ones by only using code?

Comment: This might not be the best place to ask this question. the WPML plugin has an excellent support forum, as it is WPML that controls the translations, assigning a page as a translation should involve WPML, they might have a function for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample of how to programmatically insert post and translation in PHP. Here `en` is default language and `de` is secondary language.

It's basically:

- Create both posts.
- Get the `trid` of the first one.
- Connect it with the second one.

Sample:

```
$new_page_id = wp_insert_post($new_page);
$new_page_translated_id = wp_insert_post($new_page_translated);
$wpml_element_type = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_type', get_post_type( $new_page_id ) );
$wpml_element_trid   = apply_filters( 'wpml_element_trid', false, $new_page_id, $wpml_element_type );

$set_language_args = array(
  'element_id'    => $new_page_translated_id,
  'element_type'  => $wpml_element_type,
  'trid'   => $wpml_element_trid,
  'language_code'   => 'de',
  'source_language_code' => 'en',
);

do_action( 'wpml_set_element_language_details', $set_language_args );
```